# Connect Iphone using Wireless not working

Tags: ios, xcode, wireless

I recently updated to IOS 11 and Xcode 9. Am trying to explore the option of connecting my phone over wifi with xcode for development. My mac and IPhone are both connected to same wifi (corporate network). I have selected the option for connecting my iphone over a network but as mentioned in the WWDC talk, https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/404,  there is not globe icon showing next to my device and consequently if i disconnect my iphone from usb it gives me lost connection error.

Few of device details:
Mac OS : 10.12.6 (16G29)
IPhone : 6S running IOS (1115A372)
XCode : Version 9.0 (9A235)

Am i missing some step or is there a gap in implementation here ?

Posted same question on Apple Developer forum at https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/261911

[image: Not seeing Globe icon]

Comment: I see the device and the app launches but debugger loses connection. "lost connection", so I cant debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i guess i figured this out. This feature works from my home wifi but not if both of my devices are on my corporate network. Also, as khalid mentioned the installing of app when connected via wifi, is painfully slow compared to USB option. Maybe could use usb to transfer the application and then move to wifi to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You have to connect your iPhone via USB for the first time once to Xcode wait till Xcode finishes processing. Now you can click on your device name at the top 
[image]

it will open the a list of simulators and your currently connected devices
[image]

Select the add additional simulators

[image]

Make sure that you have selected the Devices tab not Simulator also if you have multiple devices connected to your Xcode at the same time make sure to select the device you want to be connected view network in the left pan first.

Also you have to make sure that both your Computer and iPhone are both connected to the same network.

Now check the check mark for the **Connect via Network** 
Close the current window and remove the USB cable click on build it should build your project through network.

Note: Building through network very slow.

update:
Please see the glob icon your looking for in the image below

[image]

Comment: Khalid: Yes my question is about after going through all those steps as mentioned in the WWDC talk and not getting it working. The talk mentioned that as soon as XCode is done processing the work to connect your phone wirelessly, it will show a globe icon next to the phone, but i don't see that.

Comment: @adityaparikh please see the screen shot I updated with the globe icon

Comment: thanks for the screenshot, but I am aware of the location where the globe icon will appear IF IT WORKS, the problem is, IT IS NOT :D thats my concern, as you can see in the screenshot i recently attached, I have clicked on the Connect via network option but globe icon is not appearing and phone is not connected wirelessly

Comment: I think you have to undo everything a re start what you were doing. try to remove the check mark for show as run destination also connect via network. close xcode. open xcode connect your phone again do the same process again remember to wait till xcode finishes build settings for the same iPhone. Also you have to try to see that your phone is registered as your development iPhone.

Comment: Okay, I did retry all of those steps and still the same status. I have been developing for a while on my phone using usb so my phone is registered as development device

Comment: It's interesting as I have tried many times it's working without problem i think I had problem only once I reversed everything and did the process again and it worked